# static width for button, and rest for textarea

Tags: html, css

Hello I have created two divs, one is floated to the left (button), and has 120px width, and another one is for textarea, textarea should be `margin-left: 20px` and take rest of the width. How much ever I try, I am not able to achieve this. Guys, do you know the solution?

```
<div id="button" style="float: left; width: 120px; height: 80px;">
   <input type="button" id="button" value="something" />
</div>
<div id="textarea" style="margin-left: 20px;">
   <textarea id="message"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Do you want both divs on the same line next to each other?

Comment: You cannot have two ID elements with the same name `id="button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For IE8 use **#ID** named DIVs instead of `nth-child`)
**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ewuqIMO/2/edit)**

[image]

|-------- 120 --------| 20 |------ available space ----------------------------------------------------------->

```
<div id="formArea">
  <div>
   <input type="button" value="something" />
  </div>
  <div>
   <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#formArea{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#formArea>div{ 
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#formArea>div:nth-child(1){
  width:120px;
}
#formArea>div:nth-child(2){ 
  padding-left:20px;   /* instead of margin */
}
#formArea textarea{
  border:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

<sub>And remember, `ID` **must** be unique-per-page.</sub>

Comment: oh I forgot... I know, that ID must be unique, this code was only to show, what I meant :)

Comment: Hey I have a question for you, because I have added one function, and if I click on button "something", then this button's div disappear, and will be shown new div with width 350px which has two buttons, then textarea's width crashes. Do I have to show you this problem on jsbin?

Comment: @cooler Don't use unnecessary DIVs all over the place. Your HTML markup is overly complicated for such an simple structure. Put all your buttons into one DIV. So basically try to have 2 DIVs, one for ALL your buttons and the other for the textarea and job done.

Comment: haha I understand, but I use there JS to set slowly opacity to 0, and show changed button on hover :D that's why I have there a few divs, one div have normal button, and changed after hover button, that's why it may looks like :D and if put them all into one div, then I lose fade effect on hover

Comment: okai I found the reason... new div has display: block, not table-cell as it should has! thank you, have a good night sir! 
edit: I thought everything will be okay if I use jQuery, but okai, gonna try with css3, but I wanted to get this slow fade in/out effect, but anyway gonna try, thank you for advices!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.left{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
}
.right{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#message{
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="something" />
</div>
<div class="right">
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmtJR/2/)

Comment: yeah but then texarea doesn't fill rest of width. Button takes 120px, margin another 20px, and rest should be filled by textarea, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's give this one a try... Below is the code you have given us but with a few enhancements:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="button" id="button" value="something" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following is the CSS I have attached:

```
.left {
    width: 120px;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
#message{
    width:400px;
}
#container {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Now, what I have done is set all of your current divs into one main div, which can hold everything together. I implemented a display:inline-block to help keep everything on one line along with maintaining the text area to be on the right and the button on he left with the cushion you have asked for in-between. To get a better idea of what this does, I have recreated an already done [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmtJR/3/), which can accurately depict what I am describing.

A few things to note, remember that "textarea" can have the values of "rows" and "cols" which will determine how many rows and columns the text area will be, so you really do not need to have width in this aspect, especially if you need more rows vs columns.

Another thing, if you want to learn a bit more conceptually about some CSS tricks, the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/) is one of the better tools out there to help you understand "why this does that".

Last, I encourage you to play with everybody's JsFiddle to get a better understanding of exactly what you want to see in your own code, every answer that has been presented has their own unique JsFiddle.

If this does not work or you have questions, comment below and we can figure something else out :)

Good luck with your future HTML/CSS coding adventures :)

Comment: This way width of textarea is fixed and if you resize the window it will stay 400px and not 100% like it's supposed to be.

Comment: So then you can switch the width to 100%, I was just playing with values :) it should still work.

Comment: If you switch it to 100% it will work without changing another values in your css..